# I am wondering how to pass a function into an array in python?

Tags: python, function, loops

For example I have this code where I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

My Code:

```
def initialpopulation(numberofanimals, length):
    pop = []
    for i in xrange(numberofanimals):
        pop.append(individual(length))
    return pop

graded=[zip(OneAnimalSearch(radius,listsum(x),turnnum,AllotedDistance,foodcutoff,foodlist ),x) for x in initialpopulation]
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You need to call the function.

Comment: sorry I meant the OneAnimalSearch function, is it possible to create an array from its integer output

Comment: You are not passing a function to the array, you are iterating over a function which is illegal.  As @AnandSKumar mentioned, you need to call your function.

Comment: @AdamS the error is caused by this part: `for x in initialpopulation`

Comment: Oh I see so I need initialpopulation(10,10) for example